# How to customise distance between tickers on the 2nd y-axis in BokehJS

Tags: javascript, python, plot, bokeh, bokehjs

So I'm trying to create a plot with BokehJS. This plot needs 3 axes (left, right, bottom):
The plot looks like this

[image: Graph output]

As you can see, the right y-axis is pretty ugly, you can't read any data from towards the bottom as the tickers are bunched up.

This is how im creating my plot and lines

```js
function zip(arr1, arr2, floatCast){
    var out = {};
    if (floatCast){
        arr1.map( (val,idx)=>{ out[parseFloat(val)] = arr2[idx]; } );
        }
    else{
        arr1.map( (val,idx)=>{ out[val] = arr2[idx]; } );
        }
    return out;
}

function createBokehPlot(PNVibe, staticPN, transX, transY){
    //empty the previous plot
    $( "#graph-div" ).empty();

    //Data Source for PN under vibration vs. offset frequency 
    const source = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
    data: { x: Object.keys(PNVibe), y: Object.values(PNVibe) }
    });
                
    //Data source for Static PN vs offset frequency
    const source1 = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
        data: { x: Object.keys(staticPN), y: Object.values(staticPN) }
    });

    //Data source for Transmissibility line
    const source2 = new Bokeh.ColumnDataSource({
        data: { x: transX, y: transY}
    });

    //Set plot x/y ranges
    var max_offset = Math.max(Object.keys(PNVibe));
    const xdr = new Bokeh.Range1d({ start: 1, end: 100000 });
    const ydr = new Bokeh.Range1d({ start: -180, end: -50 });
    const y2_range = new Bokeh.Range1d({start: 0.001, end: 10});

    // make a plot with some tools
    const plot = Bokeh.Plotting.figure({
        title: 'Example of random data',
        tools: "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save",
        toolbar_location: "right",
        toolbar_sticky: false,
        height: 600,
        width: 700,
        outerWidth: 800,
        legend_location: "top_left",
        x_range: xdr,
        y_range: ydr,
        x_axis_type:"log",
        x_axis_label: "Offset Frequency (Hz)",
        y_axis_type: "linear",
        y_axis_label: "Phase Noise (dBc/Hz)",
        extra_y_ranges: {y2_range},
        major_label_standoff: 1
});

    //Add the second y axis on the right
    const second_y_axis = new Bokeh.LogAxis({y_range_name:"y2_range",     axis_label:'Vibration Profile (g^2/Hz)', x_range: xdr, bounds:[0.0001, 10]});
    second_y_axis.ticker = new Bokeh.FixedTicker({ticks: [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]})
    plot.add_layout(second_y_axis, "right");


    // add line for vibraiton phase noise
    plot.line({ field: "x" }, { field: "y" }, {
        source: source,
        line_width: 2,
        line_color: "red",
        legend_label: "Phase Noise under Vibrations"
        });
                
    //add line for static phase noise
    plot.line({ field: "x" }, { field: "y" }, {
        source: source1,
        line_width: 2,
        line_color: "blue",
        legend_label: "Static Phase Noise"
        });

    plot.line({ field: "x" }, { field: "y" }, {
        source: source2,
        line_width: 2,
        line_color: "green",
        y_range_name:"y2_range",
        legend_label: "Transmissibillity"
        });

    // show the plot, appending it to the end of the current section
    Bokeh.Plotting.show(plot, "#graph-div");
    return;
}

//Call function
var PNVibe = zip([10, 100, 1000], [-95, -100, -105], false);
var staticPN = zip([10, 100, 1000], [-90, -105, -110], false);
var transX = [10, 100, 1000];
var transY = [0.0005, 0.003, 0.05];
createBokehPlot(PNVibe, staticPN, transX, transY);
```

My question is, how would I be able to make it so that the right y-axis displays better? Preferably I want each tick to be the same distance from each other (ie. space between 10^0 and 10^1 is the same as space between 10^1 and 10^2)

Thanks

I also posted this on the bokeh forums:[Here](https://discourse.bokeh.org/t/how-to-make-log-axis-on-2nd-y-axis-have-bigger-distances-between-ticks/10042)

Comment: `new Bokeh.FixedTicker(ticks=[0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]` isn't  valid JS/TS as far as I know. Perhaps you mean `new Bokeh.FixedTicker({ticks: [0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10]})`

Comment: @bigreddot ah yep, it isn't proper JS. Not used to using JS yet. That line works now but it still gives me the same output as I was without either of those lines, so still having the same problem

Comment: Although you have asked for `LogAxis` the result is clearly using a linear scale, which is why the ticks at log decade intervals bunch up at the bottom. I would have to actually run real code (i.e. a [complete, minimal, reproducing example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly to try to figure out if there is a bug or a usage issue.

Comment: Hi, sorry I've now uploaded my full function in this post, it should be runnable with everything I provided. Thanks

Comment: @bigreddot ping just to make sure youve seen this. Thanks a lot

Comment: I was at work-work but it looks like you already got it sorted!  

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed my problem:

I believe I may have had some invalid javascript in my original code which is why it wasnt correctly rendering. After hours of messing around with whatever I could think of, it's fixed.

```
//Define range for y2
const y2_range = new Bokeh.Range1d({start: 0.0001, end: 10}); //Cannot use //array for this

// make a plot with some tools
const plot = Bokeh.Plotting.figure({
    title: 'Example of random data',
    tools: "pan,wheel_zoom,box_zoom,reset,save,hover",
    toolbar_location: "right",
    toolbar_sticky: false,
    height: 600,
    width: 700,
    outerWidth: 800,
    legend_location: "top_left",
    x_range: [1, 1000000],
    y_range: [-180, -70],
    x_axis_type:"log",
    x_axis_label: "Offset Frequency (Hz)",
    y_axis_label: "Phase Noise (dBc/Hz)",
    extra_y_ranges: {"y2_range": y2_range}, //This was incorrect
    extra_y_scales: {"y2_range": new Bokeh.LogScale()}, //This was incorrect
    major_label_standoff: 5,
    });

//Add the second y axis on the right
const second_y_axis = new Bokeh.LogAxis({
    y_range_name:"y2_range",
    axis_label:'Vibration Profile (g^2/Hz)',
    x_range: [1, 1000000],
    bounds:[0.0001, 10],
    });

plot.add_layout(second_y_axis, "right");
```